# Laravel MIX установка пакетов npm на примере izimodal

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Не могу корректно установить пакет izimodal в Laravel

Установил пакет с помощью `npm install`
После, инициализировал пакет `/resources/js/bootstrap.js` следующим образом:

```
import iziModal from 'izimodal/js/iziModal';
$.fn.iziModal = iziModal;
```

и запустил `npm run dev` что бы скомпилировать app.js

Каким образом необходимо корректно инициализировать css часть библиотеки? Пробовал такой вариант в `webpack.mix.js`, но он не работает...

```
mix.copy('node_modules/izimodal/css/iziModal.css', 'resources/css');

mix.styles([
    'resources/css/reset.css',
    'resources/css/style.css'
    ], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Comment: я css вендоров непосредственно в свой scss вставляю директивой `@include(...)`

Answer (score 1):

а почему не соберешь все в app.scss?

```
@import '~izimodal/css/iziModal.css';
@import '../css/reset.css';
@import '../css/style.css';
```

а в вэбпаке просто

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/style.css');
```